# How to get the BackgroundColor value for Run in Aspose.Words?

Tags: c#, aspose.words

Here is:

• Aspose.Words

• System.Drawing

If one of the main .docx document paragraph is modified (with TrackChange always enabled), you have to determine the background color (color code) of the modified run.

When a run is modified well, it is determined correctly (for example, when “client” was written instead of “contractor”, it is shown as modified run). How to get the background color code?

The document is formatted as a table. I take all the cells. In the cells, I take all the paragraphs and in the paragraphs, I take all the runs:

```
foreach(Run run in par.Runs) //par - it's Paragraph in Cells
{
    if(run.IsInsertRevision || run.IsDeleteRevision) //check revisions (in TrackChange)
    {
        Paragraph parpar = run.ParentParagraph; //taking parent paragraph

        Shading shading = builder.ParagraphFormat.Shading; //create a new shading for current paragraph
        System.Drawing.Color clr = shading.BackgroundPatternColor; //trying to get a backgroung color

        string r = clr.R.ToString("X2");
        string g = clr.G.ToString("X2");
        string b = clr.B.ToString("X2");

        r = r.Length == 1 ? "0" + r : r;
        g = g.Length == 1 ? "0" + g : g;
        b = b.Length == 1 ? "0" + b : b;

        string code = "#" + r + g + b;

        Console.WriteLine(code); //it's #000000 instead #fff001 (real backgroung color in the document)
    }
}
```

Comment: `.ToString("X2")` always returns a leading zero, so the extra code below is redundant.

Comment: Have you checked the actual values of clr.R, clr.G and clr.B?

Comment: No, it returns HEX-code without a leading zero in my case. I tried string.format before.

Comment: Actual values is 0. Black (#000000). I think, it returns just font color. Or there is a error, I don't know.

Comment: Please share the sample input document via any free file sharer server e.g. Dropbox. I will then share the code example. - I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bn3y4n4guxmf5dp/Sample.docx?dl=0 here's sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Run.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor property to get the BackgroundColor of Run node.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "Sample.docx");
Table table = (Table)doc.GetChild(NodeType.Table, 0, true);
foreach (Paragraph par in table.LastRow.LastCell.Paragraphs)
{  
    foreach (Run run in par.Runs) //par - it's Paragraph in Cells
    {
        if (run.IsInsertRevision || run.IsDeleteRevision) //check revisions (in TrackChange)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(run.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor);
        }
    }
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.